# How to install Adobe Flash Playdr on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, flash-player

Recently I had Ubuntu installed on my computer. I'm trying to install the current Flash Player. I have downloaded the file but have no idea how to install it.

I tried asking Google and it said something about my home directory which I can't even find.

Comment: Please, state which Ubuntu you are using. It highly depends on the version.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running a recent Ubuntu, try opening a `Terminal` window and running

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're running the latest stable version of the operating system. You can certainly accomplish the plugin install from the command line however I'd also like to recommend using the Ubuntu Software Center application. It simplifies the process and eliminates the need to download anything. Here are the steps:

1. Open the Ubuntu Software Center,
2. Use the search box to search for "flash player",
3. Click the Adobe Flash plugin which should appear at the top of the list, and
4. You'll see the "Install" button on the right side of the highlighted item.